# How to get into the Downloads Folder to load all the pictures?

Tags: android

I want to add the downloads folder to my code,
this is my helper class (File Paths):

```
//"storage/emulated/0" = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath().
public String ROOT_DIR = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();



public String PICTURES = ROOT_DIR + "/Pictures";
public String CAMERA = ROOT_DIR + "/DCIM/camera";
public String DOWNLOADS = ROOT_DIR + "/Download";
```

and this my class where I use this paths

```
private void init(){
        FilePaths filePaths = new FilePaths();

        //check for other folders indide "/storage/emulated/0/pictures"
        if(FileSearch.getDirectoryPaths(filePaths.PICTURES) != null){
            directories = FileSearch.getDirectoryPaths(filePaths.PICTURES);
        }
        ArrayList<String> directoryNames = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < directories.size(); i++){

            int index = directories.get(i).lastIndexOf("/");
            String string = directories.get(i).substring(index);
            directoryNames.add(string);
        }

        directories.add(filePaths.CAMERA);
        directories.add(filePaths.DOWNLOADS);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, directories); // WARUM
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        directorySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        directorySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick: selected: " + directories.get(position));

                //setup image grid for the directory chosen
                setupGridView(directories.get(position));
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });
    }
```

If I cut the downloads part out, I get all the files of the other paths but if the downloads part is inside my code, I got an Exception because the downloads files arent added to the arrayList later.

I need the correct path for the downloads.
I found this:

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
```

but this returns me a file and I need a String in my helper class.

EDIT:

Sorry, it was my fault. I got the Exception because I didnt had any pictures in my other directories. After I inserted one, my Downloads Folder was showed. I solved this error with try and catch now.

Answer (score 0):

You can get String path from **File** like this

```
String path = file.toURI().toString();
```

Comment: Sorry, it was my fault. I got the Exception because I didnt had any pictures in my other directories. After I inserted one, my Downloads Folder was showed. I solved this error with try and catch now.

Comment: :) No problem  .